# .Net5 version-tolerant assembly loading

Tags: c#, .net, assembly-resolution, assembly-loading, assemblyresolve

I have the following situation in .Net5/C# that I'm struggling to resolve.
We have Application (let's call it *Platform*) U that is able to load plugins, e.g. Plugin P, referencing Utilities U which is part of the *Platform* and shares its version.
Our idea is, that anything within minor version should be compatible, i.e. A with version 3.1.x.y should be able to load any P with version 3.1.x.y.

Now, the *Platform* was deployed with version 3.1.1.10 and Plugin P we want to load was built targeting Application A with version 3.1.1.15.

This means, *Platform* is now running with Utilities U which has the same version, 3.1.1.10. When packaging our plugins, we do not include anything that is already available in the *Platform*, in this case Utilities U.

When loading the plugin, we call:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(pathToPluginDll);
```

Not surprisingly, when loading the plugin, it also tries to load its dependency Utilities U with version 3.1.1.15 (which we do not provide at this place).

Was I want now is to simply load Utilities 3.1.1.10 that is already provided by the *Platform*. How can I achieve that?

I did quite some research but could not find anything to work. BindingRedirect seems to be an easy way to resolve this for .NET Framework, but not for .NET5 anymore.
I also experimented with [EnableDynamicLoading / RollForward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enabledynamicloading), and the deps.json file, but without success.

Thanks for any hints/help in advance. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution with [AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-6.0):

```
internal PluginLoader() {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolver;
}

...

private static Assembly AssemblyResolver(object source, ResolveEventArgs e) {
    var expectedAssembly = new AssemblyName(e.Name);
    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SingleOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name.Equals(expectedAssembly.Name));
    return VersionMatches(assembly.GetName().Version, expectedAssembly.Version) ? assembly : null;
}
```

I was hoping to find a solution on some config level (as with binding redirect), but this looks easy enough. Still, let me know if any better solutions exist.